# How to exclude first row in SQL Server 2005 Express

Tags: .net, sql-server-express, sql-server-2005-express

I want to exclude the first row from displaying from a SQL Server 2005 Express database... how do I do this?

I know how to return just the top row, but how do I return all rows, except the top row

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable 
WHERE id NOT IN (
         SELECT TOP 1 id 
         FROM yourTable 
         ORDER BY yourOrderColumn)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT *
    FROM SomeTable
    WHERE id <> (SELECT MIN(id) FROM SomeTable)
    ORDER BY id
```

Comment: Would the anonymous downvoter care to explain their objection?

Answer (score 2):

```
select * from 
    (select ROW_NUMBER() over (order by productid) as RowNum, * from products) as A
where A.RowNum > 1
```

Comment: Wouldn't that just return `A.RowNum` values instead of rows from the original table?

Comment: This was a simplified example. Edited to be more clear by adding * to subquery. Better?

Answer (score 1):

When you say you don't want the top row I assume you have some kind of `order by` that defines which row is at the top. This sample uses the `ID` column to do that.

```
declare @T table(ID int, Col1 varchar(10))

insert into @T
select 1, 'Row 1' union all
select 2, 'Row 2' union all
select 3, 'Row 3'

select ID
from @T
where ID <> (select min(ID)
             from @T)
order by ID
```