# PHP MYSQL return from row

Tags: php, mysql

I want to know if it is possible to make a mysql_query start art a certain row in the database.

I want to to start at row2 instead of row1

Comment: So you want to [exclude the first row](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7016863/how-to-exclude-first-row-in-sql-server-2005-express/7016897#7016897)?

Comment: Please see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1492297/how-to-get-all-rows-starting-from-row-x-in-mysql

Answer (score 4):

Use the `LIMIT` clause, with a very large number (larger than your rowcount) for the max records returned.  Normally, `LIMIT` is used to select a block of records, optionally beginning with an offset.  In your case, you want all records after the offset so you have to fake it with a high maximum number.

**UPDATE** I just [read the docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select.html) and `LIMIT` starts its offset at 0, so it should in fact be `LIMIT 1, 99999`

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1, 99999999999
```

On the other hand, if your first record has an identity column less than the second row, you can just do:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id < 1;
```

Comment: You should add an `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: What happens if the second row returns true but since it's the first return in the query, wouldn't that not show up since you start the limit at 2? Wouldn't the second result actually being the first one displayed?

Answer (score 2):

In relational databases like MySQL rows do not have any default order. Seriously. Even if several `SELECT * FROM table` consecutive queries appear to sort results by insertion order.

You can, however, use the [ORDER BY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/order-by-optimization.html) clause to order the rows of specific *queries*.

Additionally, the [LIMIT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html) clause allows further filtering.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you're trying to do.  You can't start at a certain row int he DB, but you can start at a certain row in the result set:

```
 SELECT * FROM tbl_name LIMIT 2, 10000;
```

Of if you explicitly need to skip a row for some reason:

```
$skip = true;
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res))
{
    if ($skip)
    {
        $skip = false;
        continue;
    }
```

Or a variety of other solutions depending on your exact problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use offset - to skip a certain number of rows - i. e.

```
SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 10, 10
```

This will skip first 10 rows and retrieve the next 10.